# Error assigning database value to CheckBox: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Tags: c#

I am developing a small system for rental cars, connected to an Oracle database, and I am using the following line of code:

```
cbMP3Player.Checked = odrDados["CDMP3PLAYER"].ToString();
```

However, this line displays the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

How do I fix this?

Comment: The `Checked` property on a CheckBox object is set to `true` if the box is checked and `false` if not.  Trying to set it to a string (`cbMP3Player.Checked = "Felipe";`) makes no sense.  Perhaps something like `cbMP3Player.Checked = odrDados["CDMP3PLAYER"] == "CheckIt";`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory.

The `Checked` property is a bool value... it can only be `true` or `false`. You're trying to assign a string to it, which isn't going to work, and it's letting you know.

Convert your database value to the correct data type:

```
cbMP3Player.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(odrDados["CDMP3PLAYER"]);
```